# Place an image that overlaps the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw / Paint Outside Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379306/draw-paint-outside-form)

Basically I'm doing a windows forms app with no borders. As a visual effect i would like to place an image at the top corner of the window but instead of it being cut off, i want it overlap the desktop.

The image would be a png and I would like it to keep it's transparency.
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379306/vc-draw-paint-outside-form - usually drawing on a transparent form is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you need to set the image box properties to stretch. Make sure the form is top most as well for the start.