# Draw on the screen without a form

Tags: c#, console, drawing, screen

Is it possible to create a big white rectangle on the screen, without using a Forms Application?

It should cover the whole screen if possible.
I know I have to use the `System.Drawing` and tried several steps, but none have actually printed anything to my screen!

Comment: Are you asking for a way to draw outside the console window?

Comment: @Tharwen yeah I meant that

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## Method 1: Call the Windows API

You need `System.Drawing` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices`. You may need to add project references to them.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
```

Add the methods to your class with P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);
```

Get a `Graphics` object for the entire screen and draw a rectangle with it:

```
IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);

SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
g.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));

g.Dispose();
ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
```

The problem with this method is that if the screen refreshes at all, the rectangle will be overwritten, making it useless for most practical applications.

## Method 2: Create a borderless form

As before, you need a project reference. This time to `System.Windows.Forms`. You'll also need `System.Drawing` again:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Make the new form, remove its borders, fill the screen with it, and put it on top of the taskbar:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.BackColor = Color.White;
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
f.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
f.TopMost = true;

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.Run(f);
```

A possible issue with this is that the user can just alt+tab away from the window. If you want to do any more complicated graphics, you'll need to write some drawing code like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55aa1t17%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). To make the form background transparent, set its `TransparentKey` to the same as its `Backolor`.

I've just tested both of these in .NET 4.5 and Windows 7, so it may be different for earlier versions. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379369/626796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277776/626796).

Comment: How do I draw to another screen instead? (e.g. screen 2 that isn't primary)

Comment: @facepalm42 Sorry, it's been 6 years. I don't remember

Comment: @facepalm42 `GetDC(0)` returns the DC from all monitors. _Maybe_ this can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53334112/1303323

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to draw to the screen but it may be easier to use a topmost, borderless form.

You can also do this from a console application, if you must, providing you reference the necessary assemblies but this would result in a console window remaining on screen for the life of the application.

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Alternatively I believe you can create an instance of `Window` and call `Show` on that.

[This answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536194/83264) explains how to use GDI+ calls to draw directly to the screen.

Comment: thx so far, but I wanted to draw this outside of the console window