# How to plot a grayscale image with a 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#, plot, scottplot

I wanted to plot my array (`double[50,50]`) in C# in similar way, as it is done in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
 
X = np.random.random((100, 100)) # sample 2D array 
plt.imshow(X, cmap="gray") 
plt.show()
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. C# doesn't have UI. You need to choose UI framework: winforms, wpf, etc. first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw on the screen without a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385838/draw-on-the-screen-without-a-form)

Comment: Unfortunately no :(